# Paginated Combo Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, combobox, pagination

I have a huge data for a simple HTML default combo box, say 3000+ and unluckily I can not reduce the data. Simply, I could populate the combo box with  3000+ records but I want the data to appear in paginated form. What's the best way to achieve this requirement. Following are the snapshots I want to achieve. I don't want a good GUI, just the pagination will do fine.

This is a default look and feel of a combo box with no pagination.

[image: Simple Default Combo Box]

I want to achieve the pagination of my results through JSON or any other source like the example below.

[image: Paginated Combo Box]

Comment: Not exactly pagination, but if finding items with a search function instead is fine you could use either [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) or [Select2](https://select2.github.io/).

Comment: did you find the solution? I need the same

Comment: @HermannGolden No, combo works fine on Firefox but get slow gradually as you scroll. Better wait for chrome to change it's engine. :)